# Connect AppEngine service to CloudRun instance on same VPC network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-run

I'm having some trouble figuring out why my AppEngine service isn't able to send requests to my CloudRun instance. For any request sent a `404 Page not found` is received.

Here's my setup:

project with a shared VPC network (mentioning it but every service is in the same project and region), the AppEngine service can connect to the shared VPC via serverless VPC connector. The CloudRun service is a simple server which exposes an api endpoint.

Now, I want my CloudRun service to allow unauthenticated requests and be reacheable only from my VPC network, so I set the `Ingress Control` to `Internal`, used the same serverless VPC connector I'm using for the AppEngine service, and set `Authentication` to `Allow unauthenticated invocations`. AppEngine can connect to google services like SQL, and a private VM I'm hosting on another project that is using the same VPC network (that's why I have a shared VPC).

I did some testing and:

- `Ingress Control` set to `all` allows me to connect to the CloudRun service locally, from a VM in the same project, and from AppEngine
- `Ingress Control` set to `Internal` allows me to connect from the VM in the same project, but not from AppEngine or locally (404 page not found)

I'm happy to share other settings if needed, I'm really struggling to figure this issue out

Comment: Neither App Engine nor Cloud Run is in your VPC. If you enable internal only, then they cannot connect to each other.

Comment: Do you use the VPC connector with App Engine? If so, did you set the egress setting to all traffic? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/connecting-vpc#egress

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes I set the egress setting to all traffic, still no luck

Comment: Review your configuration, be sure to have created the VPC connector in the correct VPC  in the correct region. It should work!

Comment: When the egress setting is set to all traffic I can't even connect to the cloud run service when public? Will do more testing tomorrow, I hope to make it work @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: All means that destination IP private AND public are routed to your VPC. Then, on your VPC you have a default internet gateway that allow the traffic to go to the internet. So no problem to access to public IP, but the traffic will be routed to your VPC before going outside!

Comment: When creating the VPC connector you can either use --network and --range flags and it creates a managed subnet for you (without private access enabled), or --subnet and --subnet-project flags. If you use the latter, and ensure the subnet created has the flag --enable-private-ip-google-access perhaps that may solve if you haven't figured it out already.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere:

> All means that destination IP private AND public are routed to your VPC. Then, on your VPC you have a default internet gateway that allow the traffic to go to the internet. So no problem to access to public IP, but the traffic will be routed to your VPC before going outside!

---

You may also check this documentation about [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc), [Routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes), and [Ingress and egress rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/ingress-egress-rules)